# Understanding the Central Limit Theorem and Chebyshev's Inequality

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, central-limit-theorem

Here is the problem I'm trying to solve:

The central limit theorem can be used to analyze round-off error.  Suppose that the round-off error is represented as a uniform random variable on [−1,1].

(i) Suppose 100 numbers are added.  Use the CLT to approximate the probability that the total round-off error exceeds 7 in absolute value (that is, greater than 7 or less than -7).

(ii) Suppose 100 numbers are added.  Use Chebyshev’s inequality to obtain an upper boundon the probability that the total round-off error exceeds 7 in absolute value.

(iii) Which is closer to the true probability,  the approximation in part (i) or the upperbound in part (ii)?  Explain.

So far part 1 I let the round off error sum of 100 numbers be represented by random variable Y. I then got $E(Y) = \sum_{i=1}^{100}E(X_i) = 0$ since $E(X_i) = 0$ for all $X_i$ in the interval. Likewise I got, $Var(Y) = \sum_{i=1}^{100}Var(X_i) = 100(\frac{1}{3}) = \frac{100}{3}$ since $Var(X_i) = \frac{1}{3}$ for all $X_i$ in the interval. I then approximated the probability that the total round-off error exceeds 7 in absolute value using the CLT. $P(Y > 7) = 1 - P(Y \leq 7) = 1 - pnorm(\frac{7-0}{\sqrt{\frac{100}{3}}}) = .1127$ in R.

I don't really understand part II. Can someone give me advice? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Chebyshev inequality gives an upper bound on the deviation of a random variable from its mean. It states that $\Pr(|X -\mu| \geq k \sigma) \leq k^{-2}$ for $k > 0$. Can you figure out the bound now?

Comment: Would I be solving for $k^{-2}$?

Comment: No. In this case you want to find $\Pr(|Y| \geq 7)  = \Pr(|Y - 0| \geq (7/\sigma) \sigma) \leq \dfrac{\sigma^2}{49}$ where $\sigma^2 = 100/3$.

Comment: Also for the CLT case, you need to evaluate $\Pr(|Y| > 7)$ and not $\Pr( Y > 7)$. So you might want to redo that calculation.

Comment: For the CLT case it would be 2(.1127) then to account for the absolute value?